# Web scraping from ortel using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Login to a web page [Ortel Website](http://cm.ortel.net) through python and scrape the next page, [Data usage page](http://cm.ortel.net/index.asp)

So, I used this code:

```
username = '0000000' 
password = 'password'
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'txtMembNumb' : username, 'txtMembPass' : password})
opener.open('http://cm.ortel.net', login_data)
resp = opener.open('http://cm.ortel.net/index.asp')
print resp.read()
```

It returns an error

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
```

> Update: Sorry the above problem was because of sublime text editor.But this program gives me the HTML file of the login page but I want the next page.

Comment: Which part of the error message is unclear? You will need to decode the data if it's encoded.

Comment: It returns a html code only.So, there is nothing  to decode right?

Comment: Every text string is in *some* encoding. See also http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Answer (score 0):

Look write your output in a function

> decode("utf8")

Like ::

```
output.decode("utf8")
```